# Jenkins build-flow plugin "build" command

Tags: jenkins-plugins, dsl, jenkins-cli

I suspect there is more fundamental learning I need before I attempt to use the build-flow plugin.

Using the DSL plugin I created a Seed job which created sub-jobs:

```
FromTemplate-Job1 to FromTemplate-Job3
```

Ultimately I want to run these in parallel. However, for now, I just want to run `FromTemplate-Job1`

I thought this could just use `build("FromTemplate-Job1")` to run the job, however this generates the exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: script1438099035271418250533.build() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [FromTemplate-Job1]
```

There is obviously something fundamental that I need to understand?

Comment: what is your job type?

Answer (score 0):

Mahi - your question was the right one to ask - Thanks .
I had chosen `FreeStyle` as the job type and not `Build Flow` - it is now working!

Comment: And now they are running in parallel too

Comment: That is strange as it didn't for me and as soon as I recreated using the Build Flow type it worked.

Answer (score 0):

DSL **build** command executes Free style job.

It won't execute job which is configured with multijob or dsl job.